# Android billing - where in the app flow is the best way to verify that the user is subscribed or not?

Tags: android

I have an application that is able to get the user to subscribe.

But I am not certain what is the best way to manage that subscription inside the app. Since the user can unsubscribe outside the app, do I need to check for the status of the subscription every time they open the app? Or will it slow down the app flow?

Or is there a better way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All of the APIs are asynchronous. It shouldn't slow your application down if you ask it to verify as the application loads and get the response when it's ready. As far as I know, it should also tell you once the subscription status changes, so there's no need to poll it. The user can fool this by disconnecting the internet connection while using your app, but the next time he connects, it should pick up on that.

If you aren't already, I'd suggest you use [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary). It's pretty easy to use and abstracts away most of the difficulties. It should be good enough for most basic cases. Just make sure you apply [this patch](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/issues/52) or get a version with it already applied.